# How to concatenate Pandas dataframes which meet specific criteria in their Multiindex columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two dataframes:

```
d1 = {('CAR','ALPHA'): pd.Series(['A11', 'A12', 'A13', 'A14'],index=[1, 2, 3, 4]),
      ('CAR','BETA'): pd.Series(['B11', 'B12', 'B13', 'B14'],index=[1, 2, 3, 4])}
da= pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
d2 = {('CAR','ALPHA'): pd.Series(['A22', 'A23', 'A24', 'A25'],index=[2, 3, 4, 5]), 
      ('CAR','BETA'): pd.Series(['B22', 'B23', 'B24', 'B25'],index=[2, 3, 4, 5]),
      ('MOTOR','SOLO'): pd.Series(['S22', 'S23', 'S24', 'S25'], index=[2, 3, 4, 5])}
db= pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

They should look like that:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to add in a new dataframe, all the columns of the two dataframes that have the a specific word in one of the Column index.

For example I would like to have all the columns that have CAR in the top column level:

[image]

My pandas version is 0.21.0 and the column names in my complicated version of the code are the following:

```
df = pd.concat([da, db], axis=1)
print(df.columns)
Index([('V', 'C', 'I', 'P'),
       ('V', 'G', 'T', '-'),
       ('P', 'G', 'T', '-')], dtype='object')
```

And on the above, I want to keep only the columns with V in the first level of the column multiindex.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df = pd.concat([da, db], axis=1).xs('CAR', level=0, axis=1, drop_level=False)
```

Or use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
df = pd.concat([da, db], axis=1).loc[:, pd.IndexSlice['CAR', :]]
```

---

```
print (df)
    CAR                
  ALPHA BETA ALPHA BETA
1   A11  B11   NaN  NaN
2   A12  B12   A22  B22
3   A13  B13   A23  B23
4   A14  B14   A24  B24
5   NaN  NaN   A25  B25
```

EDIT:

There is 4 levels DataFrame, so need:

```
idx = pd.Index([('V', 'C', 'I', 'P'),
       ('V', 'G', 'T', '-'),
       ('P', 'G', 'T', '-')], dtype='object')
df = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=idx, index=[1,2])
print (df)
   V     P
   C  G  G
   I  T  T
   P  -  -
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0


df1 = df.xs('V', level=0, axis=1, drop_level=False)
print (df1)
   V   
   C  G
   I  T
   P  -
1  0  0
2  0  0
```

Add `:` for each level for select all values of second, third ans forth levels:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice['V', :, :, :]]
print (df1)
   V   
   C  G
   I  T
   P  -
1  0  0
2  0  0
```

Comment: In my original more complex code, the operation df = pd.concat([da, db], axis=1) works perfectly. However, the df = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice['CAR', :]] returns an error unhashable type: 'slice' .

Comment: @Thanasis I have few questions. 1. What is your pandas version? 2. Error is with sample data from question? 3. What is `print (df. columns)` after `concat`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `isin`

```
pd.concat([da,db.loc[:,db.columns.isin(da.columns)]],1)
Out[733]: 
    CAR                
  ALPHA BETA ALPHA BETA
1   A11  B11   NaN  NaN
2   A12  B12   A22  B22
3   A13  B13   A23  B23
4   A14  B14   A24  B24
5   NaN  NaN   A25  B25
```